# How to do a complex negative lookbehind to split tokens in Java?

Tags: java, regex, tokenize, regex-negation

I have a number of lines in EDIFACT format that need to be tokenized on `+`.  However, according to the EDIFACT spec, characters can be escaped with a `?`.  For example: `??` for a `?`, `?+` for a `+`, `?:` for a `:`.  A `?+` is part of the field and should hence not be considered a delimiter.

I used negative lookbehind to deal with `+`'s that are followed by a `?`:

```
delimiter = "\\+";
String[] tokens = data.split("(?<!\\?)" + delimiter);
```

This would split up

`a+b+c` into `a`, `b` and `c`

`a?+b+c` into `a?+b` and `c`

However, it fails when an `??` escape sequence is involved:

`a??+b+c` yields 2 tokens: `a??+b`, `c`

whereas it really should be 3 tokens: `a?`, `b` and `c`

On the other hand: `a???+b+c` should yield two tokens: `a???+b` and `c`

Is there a way to achieve this using negative lookbehind?

Here's a runnable test to play around if you wish.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      assertTokens("a+b+c", "a", "b", "c");
      assertTokens("a?+b+c", "a?+b", "c");
      assertTokens("a??+b+c", "a??", "b", "c");
      assertTokens("a???+b+c", "a???+b", "c");
   }

   private static void assertTokens(String data, String... expectedTokens) {
      String delimiter = "\\+";
      String[] tokens = data.split("(?<!\\?)" + delimiter);

      if(!Arrays.deepEquals(tokens, expectedTokens)) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Not equals for " + data);
      }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than splitting, tokenization is easier using matching. In your case, for split to work you'd have to use a variable-length lookbehind which java doesn't support.

Try the following regex:

```
(?:[^+:?]++|\?.)+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lQ5qS3/1)

(I've used a possessive quantifier (`++`) purely as an optimization to avoid useless backtracking)

---

If you want to match empty tokens (`a++b` yielding, `a`, an empty string and `b`), the regex gets more complicated:

```
(?:[^+:?\r\n]++|\?.)+|(?<=[+:]|^)(?=[+:]|$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lQ5qS3/2)

Which means

- Either match the same as above (I've just added `\r\n` to the group so newlines don't match)
- Or an empty string which is:

  - preceded by a token delimiter or the start of the line
  - and followed by a token delimiter or the end of the line

I've added the `m` option for this to work, meaning `^` and `$` match the start and end of each line.

Comment: Hey Lucas, I did misunderstand you, sorry.  The above pattern matching works beautifully :) thank you.

Comment: Lucas, while we're at it.  EDIFACT allows also delimiting by colons (:).  What would the regex look like in that case?

Comment: @javacoder just replace the `[^+?]` part with `[^+:?]` - basically match everything except the special characters of the language

Comment: sorry, mistakenly changed the possessive quantifier as well

Comment: Is there a way to return the empty tokens? Eg. a++b returns a, empty string and b ?

Comment: @javacoder Yes that's important and I overlooked this. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

For reference:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        assertTokens("+", "a+b+c", "a", "b", "c");
        assertTokens("+", "a?+b+c", "a?+b", "c");
        assertTokens("+", "a??+b+c", "a??", "b", "c");
        assertTokens("+", "a???+b+c", "a???+b", "c");
        assertTokens("+", "a?'??+b+c", "a?'??", "b", "c");

        assertTokens("\\:", "a???:b:c", "a???:b", "c");
        assertTokens("\\:", "a????:b:c", "a????", "b", "c");
    }

    private static void assertTokens(String delim, String data, String... expectedTokens) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:[^" + delim + ":?]++|\\?.)+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

        List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
        while (matcher.find()) {
            tokens.add(matcher.group());
        }

        if(!Arrays.deepEquals(tokens.toArray(), expectedTokens)) {
            for (String token: tokens) {
                System.out.println(token);
            }
            throw new IllegalStateException("Not equals for " + data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really use that possessive quantifier (look at [this](http://regex101.com/r/fK9kQ1/1) and the related [explanation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)).

Comment: I noticed, changed the answer.  Thanks for the links, I'll read up on them.  On the top of your head, can you come up with a pattern in the above example that would perform really bad without that possissive quantifier?

Comment: I think I was alarming you too much about this... I can't figure out an input which would make it fail mostly because the real dangerous pattern is like `(X+)+Y`, and in your case, there's no `Y`.

Comment: Unless the input is always valid, when you tokenize with regex, `\G` should be used to make sure you are not skipping over invalid syntax in the string.